# Why every time I install a package with npm or yarn it installs all the dependencies?

Tags: npm, installation, yarnpkg

every time I install a dependency, for example `yarn add socketio`, instead of installing that dependency alone it installs all the ones from the `package.json`. Is there a way that I only install the dependency that I indicate and not all?

Comment: Why are there dependencies in the package file that aren't already installed, and why do you want to leave your project in that state?

Answer (score 2):

Checked with `v1.22.0`.

This should only happen if you have a `package.json` file and its dependencies are not installed.

Consider the example, where you have [underscore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/underscore) as dependency in `package.json` and somehow it is not installed yet. Now, you're trying to install let's say [color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/color) package. In this case, yarn will install color as well as underscore as dependencies. But, once all the dependencies mentioned in `package.json` are installed, yarn will not install dependencies again.